# LU Decomposition on GPU MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gpu, linear-algebra, scientific-computing

I am trying to run LU Decomposition on MATLAB such that it will use the GPU.
According to NVidia/MATLAB documentation, LU is supposed to be supported by CUDA (see, for example http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2267_GTC2010.pdf).

Now, I have compared the speeds between CPU and GPU, and while GPU is indeed faster for matrix multiplication and FFT it seems to give pretty much the same results for LU decomposition, which is very important to me.

I have tried it for different sizes, but it remains pretty much the same.

For instance,

On GPU:

```
A=gpuArray(randn(1000));
tic; [l,u,p]=lu(A); toc
Elapsed time is 0.056832 seconds.
```

On CPU:

```
B=randn(1000);
tic; [l,u,p]=lu(B); toc
Elapsed time is 0.031463 seconds.
```

CPU is even faster. My CPU is i7-2630QM and my GPU is GT-550M (Laptop).
I also tried it on a stronger computer that has GTX-660 and the results were the same.

My MATLAB version is 2012b

Comment: Believe it or not, sometimes parallelizing code can make it slower. This usually happens due to the size of the data. How does it run with various (larger) array sizes? For many methods you have to reach a certain size before GPU speeds really take off. (Even though 1000by1000 seems sufficiently big...)

Comment: Type `gpuDevice` in your command window. You'll see that the GT-550M has a very anemic `'ComputeCapability'`. You need >= 1.3 [to even use GPU functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html). Compare this to the Tesla cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MATLAB R2013a on a Tesla C2070, I see this:

```
A = gpuArray.randn(1000);
tic; [l,u,p]=lu(A); toc
Elapsed time is 0.016663 seconds.
```

which is about 2x faster than my CPU. As the matrix size increases further, the speedup increases, on my machine peaking at about 5x faster on the GPU - this is typical for a high-end (albeit slightly old) GPU compared to a decent 6-core CPU.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on a different computer that has Tesla C1060 with 8-Core CPU and I managed to get about it to be about x2 faster on the Tesla. Moreover, when I started MATLAB to run on a single core mode, using the flag "-singleCoreThread" then the GPU was much faster. It seems that some functions are run on multi-core automatically without using specifying it using "distributed" and so on.

Comment: Yes, many things in MATLAB are intrinsically multi-threaded in recent releases - which is often why you need a relatively powerful GPU to beat MATLAB's state-of-the-art CPU implementations for things like linear algebra.